# Clustering of set of customers having heterogeneous variables

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-science, data-analysis

I have set of customers with different attributes continuous, categorical, binary and ordinal.
How can I cluster them knowing that we cannot apply the same distance metrics on the these different types of attributes?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned already daisy package is an option which does an automatic selection of best distance metric based on data type.But I would suggest the following approach and request expert to please chime in.

Rather than automatic selection identify and remove some correlated variables like(some examples)
Pearson Correlation: for continuous variable
Chi Square Test: for categorical variables
Categorical vs Numerical: One way Anova test etc.

Taking the subset of useful variables consider doing One-Hot Encoding of categorical variables and maybe convert ordinal to continuous (or categorical and one-hot encode). Test using different distance metric like Euclidean, Manhattan etc to evaluate the result. You will get a better clarity of the overall clustering process in this way.